# Rails Multiple forms in one view rendering errors issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have built a dashboard of sorts with multiple forms from different models in the same view. My goal is to have all of the error messages from each form render on the dashboard. The dashboard is part of the PagesController and the forms belong to other controllers.

All of the forms currently work great. However, when errors occur they render in other views not the dashboard. When I attempt to "render" the errors on the dashboard page I get errors that the other form's models are missing.

Example of "render" that renders outside of the dashboard view.

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @note = Note.new(params[:note])
        if @note.save
            flash[:notice] = "Note Created!"
            redirect_to dashboard_path
        else
            flash[:alert] = "Note failed"
            render :action => "new"
        end
    end
 end
```

The example I would like to work, which renders the errors inside the dashboard view.

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @note = Note.new(params[:note])
        if @note.save
            flash[:notice] = "Note Created!"
            redirect_to dashboard_path
        else
            flash[:alert] = "Note failed"
            render 'pages/home'
        end
    end
 end
```

To reiterate, I am trying to make it so all errors will show up on the dashboard page with out breaking the site. Let me know if you would like more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplished this by just setting errors to an instance variable that all the forms use:

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @note = Note.new(params[:note])
        if @note.save
            flash[:notice] = "Note Created!"
            redirect_to dashboard_path
        else
            @errors = @note.errors
            load_home
            render 'pages/home'
        end
    end

    private

    def load_home
      @instances = Model.all
      @instance_1 = Model.find(1)
    end
 end
```

All your controllers would set @errors = @model.errors then in your view you just have something like this instead of relying on f.error_messages or whatever you have in your form:
(in haml)

```
- unless @errors.nil?
  #errorExplanation
    %h2 Please correct these errors
    %ul
      - for e in @errors
        %li= e[1]
```

Comment: I may be understanding this incorrectly, but when I use render 'pages/home' my view fails to load. I suspect that it's do to 'pages/home' not having all the necessary instance variables loaded. since render is rendering the pages/home  view but not the  pages/home action which has the instance variables.

Comment: It looks like I need something like this gem, https://github.com/rails/render_component , I am just trying to figure out if there is a proper way to do this in rails.

Comment: You can just create a load_home private method that does the instance variable loading for you. (edited answer)